# How to run the test files by using the testng.xml

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, testng.xml

[image: Project Structure]

I have created a project as per the above package structure and I'm facing an issue on running the test's
by the **testng.xml** file I manually created.

All the **test classes** reside in their own packages under the **API** package, and the **API** package consists of each module of the application as packages where test classes are defined in their respective module packages.

In the attached screenshot im referring only one package to be run from the **testng.xml** file and when running the file it displays as "No tests were found"

below is a code segment of **ApprovalGroupManagementApi.class** where the test methods are in with propper **TestNG** annotations.

```
package com.api.approval_group_management;
import com.base.Base;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import com.payloads.request.classes.CreatedUserList;
import com.payloads.request.classes.StatusList;
import com.payloads.request.payload.SecCreateApprovalLevel;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static com.utils.Constant.SEC_CREATE_APPROVAL_LEVEL_URL;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class ApprovalGroupManagementApi extends Base {

    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    Assertion hardAssert = new Assertion();

    @Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true, enabled = true)
    public void secCreateApprovalLevel() {
        try {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            SecCreateApprovalLevel secCreateApprovalLevel = new SecCreateApprovalLevel();
            StatusList statusList = new StatusList();
            CreatedUserList createdUserList = new CreatedUserList();
            List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

            secCreateApprovalLevel.setName("" + new Faker().name().firstName());
            secCreateApprovalLevel.setApprovalLevelAvailable(true);
            secCreateApprovalLevel.setStatusList(statusList);
            secCreateApprovalLevel.setCreatedUserList(createdUserList);
            secCreateApprovalLevel.setPrivilageList(objects);

            String approvalGroup = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(secCreateApprovalLevel);

            RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
            Response response = given().spec(resourceApiRequestSpecification).log().all()
                    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                    .when()
                    .body(approvalGroup)
                    .post(SEC_CREATE_APPROVAL_LEVEL_URL);

            //response code assertion
            hardAssert.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 200);
            softAssert.assertAll();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the package name to `name="com.api.approval_group_management"` in testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite 1">
    <test name="Regression 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.java.com.api.approval_group_management.ApprovalGroupManagementApi" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please try this It might help you to execute testng class.
(Apart from this also make sure the plugin of testng is already installed.)

Comment: can you please provide error stack what you received ?
It might help to setup initially. 
https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/getting-started-with-webdriver-in-java-using-intellij-on-windows